# Limits of indeterminate forms

Tags: limits

I am trying to find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sin(x^n)}{(\sin x)^m}$. I have tried to apply L'Hospital's rule but I get $n(x)^{n-1}$ as a term in numerator and cannot eliminate $x$ and so cannot bring it to a simple form. Can someone help me?

Comment: you must consider several cases $$n=m,n>m,n<m$$

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{sin(x^n)}{(sin x)^m}=\frac{sin(x^n)}{x^n}*(\frac{x}{sin x})^m*x^{n-m}$.

Your turn !

Comment: Excellent hint (in fact...answer) .+1

Comment: Yes Fred, you are right. The option for the answer was the limit is 1 if m = n and this satisfies.